# Calling a html file with my style sheets in is causing validation error

Tags: php, html, validation, w3c-validation

I have created a php static site and I use this following code to pick up a html file with the style sheets / javascript files in:

```
<?php require($DOCUMENT_ROOT . "styles.html");?>
```

This works on all browsers but when validating it, it comes up with the following errors:

document type does not allow element "link" here

```
<link type="text/css" href="style/style.css?v=2.1">
```

The html file does not have `<html>`, `<head>` or `<body>` as that caused different errors.

What is the best approach for this?

Comment: Why are you showing us PHP code? What matters is the final HTML document the browser sees. You probably put the `<link>` element in a place where it doesn't belong (e.g. within `<body>` instead of `<head>`)

Comment: Wait a second.. Where are you printing your <link> tag? In the head or in the body? if in the body, echo it in the head. Also, you shoul close link tags with "/>"!

Comment: While the `<html>`, `<head>` and `<body>` **tags** are optional, putting them in will make it easier for you to figure out where in a document you are. If putting them in causes errors, then addressing those errors will make it easier to fix this one.

Comment: Why is your style sheet an html file?

Comment: ThiefMaster you are correct thank you. the site is in PHP but I have set up the code so it calls in the style.html file in. I had it in the body instead of the head. It now validates - thank you!

Comment: @briosheje No tags should *ever* be closed with `/>` in HTML, only XML.

Comment: @rink.attendant.6 it is perfectly acceptable to close void elements with `/>`. See [here](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#syntax-elements): "**Optionally, a "/" character, which may be present only if the element is a [void element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/syntax.html#void-element).**"